# How to by-pass user interactions in a script?

Tags: linux, shell, expect

I am trying to automate the installation of a program through a shell script. There are a few steps which require user interaction from the command line (confirmation, yes/no, etc.). What is the best way to by-pass it? I know that one possibility is to use an expect script. Just wanted to know if there is a better/cleaner way to do this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the interaction is simple, i.e. only reads from the standard input, you can just send the particular lines to the program's input:

```
( echo yes ; echo 1024; echo yes ) | install.sh
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do anything that doesn't just read from stdin (e.g. ftp login) you'll want to use [expect](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect).

Answer (score 1):

From another thread:

If your command doesn't care how fast you give it input, and you don't really need to interact with it, then you can use a heredoc.

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash
command_you_want_to_execute <<EOD
interaction_1
intereaction_2
EOD
```

If you need branching based on the output of the program, or if your program is at all sensitive to the timing of your commands, then Expect is what you want.